# How would I create this specific table from this dataset in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a CSV containing some COVID-19 data. I am trying to create a table that will display information only about Hawaii. I want the index to be dates, and the columns to be counties in Hawaii.

```
df_counties = pd.read_csv('us-counties.csv')
df_counties
```

[Code output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzV1D.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this maybe to remove everything other than Hawaii:

```
df_hawaii = df_counties[df.counties = Hawaii]
```

And maybe this might work to get columns being the counties:

```
df_hawaii.pivot(index=df.index, columns='county', values=['fips', 'cases', 'deaths']
```

cant say for sure if this will work without testing it, but worth a shot?

Forgot to add, you can use this to set your index to whatever you want:

```
df_hawaii.set_index('date')
```